# Equality of rows and columns of a table with numbers

Tags: combinatorics

In a table of size $m \times n$, numbers are written so that the sum of the numbers in each row and in each column is equal to $10$.

> How to prove that $m = n$?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

The sum of all the rows is equal to ________?

The sum of all the columns is equal to ________?

But those two sums have to be equal (why?)

Comment: It is unclear why these amounts should be equal? And why should it follow that $m = n$?

Comment: Each row sums to 10. How many rows are there?

Comment: The sum of all the rows is equal to $10m$, sum of all the columns is equal to $10n$. Why it should follow from here that $m = n$?

Comment: But when you add up all the rows, you're effectively adding which elements of the matrix?

Comment: I don't understand Your question. OK. Suppose that $n = m + 1$. We know that the sum of all rows is equal to $10m$, the sum of all columns is equal to $10(m + 1)$. How to get the contradiction?

Comment: No need for contradiction -- it's a direct proof.

Comment: You're one step away from the finish.

Comment: When you add up all the rows, are there any elements of the matrix that _don't_ get added? Does any element get added more than once? So back to my previous question: When you add up all the rows, you're effectively adding which elements of the matrix?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not from English-speaking countries. Can you more explain what it means phrase "effectively adding which elements of the matrix"?

Comment: In other words, you can add up all the rows as a product $10{\times}m$, but you can also add them one element at a time. If you add them one element at a time, how many elements do you need to add to get the sum of all the rows? Did any element of the matrix not get used?

Comment: How many elements do you need to add the get the sum of all the rows? -- -- $m \times n$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Now try the same idea with the columns.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now understand this idea.

Comment: You're welcome.  Note that for _any_ matrix, the sum of all the rows must equal the sum of all the columns, since either way, you're effectively adding _all_ the elements of the matrix.

Comment: What you've used is called "double counting", right?

Comment: @Xam -- I guess it could be viewed that way, although in this case, it's _summing_ the same elements in different ways, rather than counting.